# How do i grep only rows with string length <= x?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I know this is a really basic question, but im struggling with the operators and i cant find the answer to my question.
Im trying to use !grepl to delete only rows with string lenght <= 2.
I tried something like (and didnt have success):

```
 df[!grepl(nchar() <= 2, df$string_column),]
```

I also tried to refer to the two characters, as shown below:

```
df[!grepl("ab", df$string_column),]
```

I know that i can do it using for loops and if conditions, but i hope there is a simpler solution using grepl...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
df[nchar(df$string_column) > 2, ]
```

grepl is used for string matching (either exact or partial) 
nchar is vectorized, so it will operate on the whole column at once

Comment: Error in nchar(wordfreq$words) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector 
im receiving this same error...

Comment: ok, i added as.character() and it worked! Thx so much!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use grepl, just the logical comparator `<=`, and `nchar()`:

```
df[nchar(as.character(df$string))<=2,]
```

Comment: Actually im receiving this error trying your solution:Error in nchar(wordfreq$words) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Comment: ok, i added as.character() and it worked! Thx so much!

Comment: Thats because your vector was probably not character